# Is it possible to perform math in a custom url

Tags: custom-url

I have a custom button to create a new opportunity from a contact record. This button passes variables to prepopulate fields on the opportunity. I also have a roll-up field on the account that counts the number of opportunities. Is it possible to increment that roll-up field when passing it to the new opportunity?

For example, I want my Opportunity Name to be the Account name and the number of opportunities  + 1, opp3={!Account.Name}{!Account.Opportunity_Count__c} + 1

If it's possible, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you tried this- ‘opp3={!Account.Name & (Account.Opportunity_Count__c+1)}’ it might need some tweak to have null check.

Comment: I tried that and received an error. Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number

Comment: `opp3={!Account.Name & TEXT(Account.Opportunity_Count__c+1))}`

Comment: that did not work either.  error: missing }

Comment: opp3={!Account.Name & TEXT(Account.Opportunity_Count__c+1)}

Comment: That doesn't work either.  Only the account name gets passed.

Comment: It would be easier if you used a workflow rule to set the opp name and in your button URL just set the opp name to "[set by workflow rule]"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. I recommend that you use URLFOR to save yourself the headache of parameter encoding (which is, coincidentally, why your formula isn't working as you expected):

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, [opp3=Account.Name & " " & 
    TEXT(Account.Opportunity_Count__c+1)], true)}
```

If you're in a formula that doesn't allow URLFOR, then make sure you properly encode your parameter:

```
/006/e?opp3={!Account.Name}%20{!Account.Opportunity_Count__c+1}
```

Note that "%20" is a "space" that's been encoded. If you put in a normal space (" "), the browser may not encode it correctly or transmit correctly, because " " is not allowed in a URL; the underlying protocol uses a " " to separate the values sent to the server, such as `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`, which specifies the action ("GET"), the file to retrieve ("/index.html"), and the version of the protocol to use ("HTTP/1.1").